# JOption Panel for a game

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make a game, at the start, the first part is fine, however, I cannot get the second question working, I would like it to display: rules_yes if Yes is entered (case insensitive), and rules_no to be displayed if anything else is written. At the moment, no matter what I input for the rules, it only runs the rules_yes. Can I get some feed back on how to make this work?

```
{
String user_name;
String name_answer;
String yes_no;
String rules_yes;
String rules_no;
char input;
private char yes;
private char Yes;

{
    user_name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your Name");

    name_answer = ("Hello " + user_name + " Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe, Click OK to Start");

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, name_answer );
}

{
    yes_no = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like the rules (Y/N)");


    if (input == Yes || input == yes)
    {

        rules_yes = ("Yes? The Rules: X goes first, each player takes turns to put their symbol in one of nine boxes, you cannot put your symbol in a box which already contains a symbol, the first one to make a row of three wins");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, rules_yes );
    }
    else
    {

    rules_no = ("No? Well too bad, here are the rules, The Rules: X goes first, each player takes turns to put their symbol in one of nine boxes, you cannot put your symbol in a box which already contains a symbol, the first one to make a row of three wins");

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, rules_no );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many issues with your code, and many things you can do to simplify it.

1. `yes` and `Yes` are not initialized, this caused your program to fail.
2. You can declare `yes_no` as a `String`, then use `if (yes_no.equalsIgnoreCase("y");`(rather than using `char yes` and `char Yes`)
3. This does not affect your program, but you have a lot of spacing between lines, which makes it seem like a lot more than it is.
4. `input` is unnecessary, so you can just delete it.

So your final code can look like this:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ScratchPaper {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        String userName;
        String nameAnswer;
        String rulesYes;
        String rulesNo;
        String yesNo;

        userName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your Name");
        nameAnswer = ("Hello " + userName + " Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe, Click OK to Start");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, nameAnswer );
        yesNo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like the rules (Y/N)");


        if (yesNo.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) 
        {
            rulesYes = ("Yes? The Rules: X goes first, each player takes turns to put their symbol in one of nine boxes, you cannot put your symbol in a box which already contains a symbol, the first one to make a row of three wins");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, rulesYes );
        }
        else {
            rulesNo = ("No? Well too bad, here are the rules, The Rules: X goes first, each player takes turns to put their symbol in one of nine boxes, you cannot put your symbol in a box which already contains a symbol, the first one to make a row of three wins");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, rulesNo );
        }
    }
}
```

If you have any questions, please comment below, and I will answer them as soon as I can. Thank you!

Comment: You also used excessive curly braces, but I figured that was just your code-writing style.

Comment: Thank you for giving me advice, you are a real life saver. And about the curly braces, that is just a habit, I kind of do it without thinking. Thanks again

Comment: @EkinYelken I forgot to mention, using underscores in variables is usually not used in java; it will not affect your program, but it is discouraged(I'm not sure why). So your variables like `user_name` and `name_answer` should be written like `userName` or `nameAnswer`

Answer (score 0):

Because you adding (Y/N) question value to "yes_no" param, but your 'if-else' condition working with 'input' so the input not initialized thats mean it's equals to 0.That's why your question always returning YES.

Change your code like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String user_name;
    String name_answer;
    String yes_no;
    String rules_yes;
    String rules_no;
    char[] input;
    char Yes = 0;

    {
        user_name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your Name");

        name_answer = ("Hello " + user_name + " Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe, Click OK to Start");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, name_answer);
    }

    {
        yes_no = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like the rules (Y/N)");

        input = yes_no.toCharArray();
        if (input[0] == Yes) {

            rules_yes = ("Yes? The Rules: X goes first, each player takes turns to put their symbol in one of nine boxes, you cannot put your symbol in a box which already contains a symbol, the first one to make a row of three wins");

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rules_yes);
        } else {

            rules_no = ("No? Well too bad, here are the rules, The Rules: X goes first, each player takes turns to put their symbol in one of nine boxes, you cannot put your symbol in a box which already contains a symbol, the first one to make a row of three wins");

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rules_no);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using an "input" dialog?

An easier solution would be to just use a "message" dialog with "Yes", "No" buttons for the user to click on.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more information and examples.